# Retun parameters while creating BGP Group in Alibaba Cloud VPC

Tags: alibaba-cloud

BGP group is used for communication between the Virtual Border Router (VBR) and the local IDC in Alibaba cloud VPC. I create a BGP Group using below mentioned command:

```
https://vpc.aliyuncs.com/?Action=CreateBgpGroup
&RegionId=cn-beijing
&PeerAsn=2010
&RouterId=vbr-2zeff11o2sqhnp1u7ci93
&CommonParameters
```

But how can I get Return Parameters (i.e. RequestID & BgpGroupID)?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/63231.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.103.4c0559d8LKgNw6 you should have received a response in XML or JSON format.

[image]

What was your response?

Comment: Let me go through it.